# how to get id of table in relationship to use in other table in this relation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

i have relation between `Service` and `Services_Gallery` one to many, and i want to use id of `Service` when i insert new image to `Services_Gallery`, and this is my Controller:

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,svg|max:1024'
    ]);

    $services_Gallery               = new Services_Gallery();
    $services_Gallery->image        = $request->image->move('Uploads', str_random('6') . time() . $request->image->getClientOriginalName());
    $services_Gallery->Service::all(id) = $request->service_id; //The problem here 
    $services_Gallery->save();
    return back();
}
```

this is my Models:

```
class Service extends Model
{
protected $table = 'services';
protected $fillable = [
    'en_main_title',
    'ar_main_title',
    'en_sub_title',
    'ar_sub_title',
    'en_content_title',
    'ar_content_title',
    'en_content',
    'ar_content',
    'priority',
];

public function gallery()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Services_Gallery','service_id');
}
}
class Services_Gallery extends Model
{
protected $table = 'services_galleries';
protected $fillable = [
    'image',
    'service_id',
];

public function gallery(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Service','service_id');
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look ok  $services_Gallery->Service::all(id) = $request->service_id;  Please paste your relations too.

Comment: @CalinBlaga i'm edit it

Comment: why not $services_Gallery->service_id = $request->service_id; ?

Comment: @CalinBlaga because user not typing number of id, just enter to edit this service and find input to add new images

Comment: @CalinBlaga ???

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand from where do you want to fetch that service_id to store it in the new service_Gallery object. If it's from a form then $request->input ('service_id') should be fine(don't know if $request->service_id is ok).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159576/discussion-between-calin-blaga-and-mohammad-hamdy).

Answer (score 0):

Exapmle:

```
$modelOfService = Service::where('param_x', $request->service_id)->first();
$id = $modelOfService->id;
```

Is that you need?

Comment: `ErrorException (E_NOTICE)`
`Trying to get property of non-object`